# Rodo no browser meu WebService e me dá uma mensagem estranha

Tags: web-service, winforms, rest, wcf

Ao dar um View In Browser no meu WebService, me trouxe essa mensagem. Não parece com uma mensagem de que o WebService está tudo ok. Que mensagem é essa?

```
Service

This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.

Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.

If you have access to the service, you can enable metadata publishing by completing the following steps to modify your web or application configuration file:

1. Create the following service behavior configuration, or add the <serviceMetadata> element to an existing service behavior configuration:

<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
2. Add the behavior configuration to the service:

<service name="MyNamespace.MyServiceType" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation.

3. Add the following endpoint to your service configuration:

<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint.

The following is an example service configuration file with metadata publishing enabled:

<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>

        <services>
            <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
            <service name="MyNamespace.MyServiceType" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
                <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                    <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
For more information on publishing metadata please see the following documentation: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
```

Estou engatinhando com WCF a passos lentos. Fui adicionar uma referência ao meu projeto windows forms para consumir o método do web service e veja o que ocorreu. Entendi que REST não se adiuciona referência, certo?

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Na minha solution tenho alguns projetos. Um projeto class library onde tenho uma classe POCO e uma Interface.

```
namespace V99SuporteTecnicoContracts
    { 
        [Table(Name="T_PDV")]
        [DataContract(Namespace="")]
        public class TPDV
        {
            [Column]
            [DataMember]
            public int IDPdv { get; set; }
            [Column]
            [DataMember]
            public string CNPJ { get; set; }
            [Column]
            [DataMember]
            public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }
    ......
```

e a minha interface

```
namespace V99SuporteTecnicoContracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISuporteTecnicoContract
    {
        [OperationContract]
        //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{_cnpj}")]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string _cnpj);
    }
}
```

Bem, além disso tenho o svc propriamente dito. Abaixo o fonte dele

```
namespace SuporteTecnicoService
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class SuporteTecnico : ISuporteTecnicoContract
    {
        public TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string _cnpj)
        {
            V99_WEB_QAEntities db = new V99_WEB_QAEntities();
            TPDV pdv = new TPDV();
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();
            //DataContext contexto = new DataContext();

            var resultado = (from _lista in db.T_PDV
                             where _lista.CNPJ == _cnpj
                             select new { _lista.CNPJ, _lista.RazaoSocial, _lista.Endereco}).ToList();

            foreach (var lis in resultado)
            {
                pdv.CNPJ = lis.CNPJ;
                pdv.RazaoSocial = lis.RazaoSocial;
                pdv.Endereco = lis.Endereco;
            }

            return pdv;
        }
    }
}
```

e o web.config do serviço(.SVC)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="V99_QAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.V99.csdl|res://*/Models.V99.ssdl|res://*/Models.V99.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=54.187.114.104;initial catalog=V99;persist security info=True;user id=V99App;password=V99@1032ab;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="V99_WEB_QAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.V99_Web.csdl|res://*/Models.V99_Web.ssdl|res://*/Models.V99_Web.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=54.187.114.104;initial catalog=V99_WEB;persist security info=True;user id=V99App;password=V99@1032ab;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="V99_OLAP_QAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.V99_Olap.csdl|res://*/Models.V99_Olap.ssdl|res://*/Models.V99_Olap.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=54.187.114.104;initial catalog=V99_OLAP;persist security info=True;user id=V99App;password=V99@1032ab;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SuporteTecnico">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="V99SuporteTecnicoContracts.ISuporteTecnicoContract" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment--> 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
           <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information--> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Quando eu tento usar o WCF Client, ele não me disponibiliza o campo referente a entrar com meu parâmetro cnpj. Creio que tem "boi na linha" do web.config.

Minha nova tag service.model no web.config.

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
           <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment--> 
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
           <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information--> 
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Fiz alterações em meu App.config e ficou assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="TesteWebService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>

      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="WebBehavior">
            <webHttp />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISuporteTecnicoContract" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISuporteTecnicoContract"
                contract="SuporteTecnicoContractClient.ISuporteTecnicoContract"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISuporteTecnicoContract" />

            <endpoint address="http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="V99SuporteTecnicoContracts.ISuporteTecnicoContract"
                behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISuporteTecnicoContract" />


          </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <applicationSettings>
        <TesteWebService.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="TesteWebService_ServiceSuporteTecnico_SuporteTecnico"
                serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost:4600/SuporteTecnicoService.svc</value>
            </setting>
        </TesteWebService.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

A mensagem agora mudou. É uma mensagem em runtime e a mensagem é essa:

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response:(400) bad request.
```

Comment: Tem como mandar um *screenshot* do seu WCF Client? Isso está muito misterioso... Aqui funcionou tão depressa... :(

Comment: Vou enviar todo o meu projeto. Tem como anexar arquivo aqui no forum?

Comment: Infelizmente, não há essa possibilidade.

Answer (score 3):

Essa é mensagem padrão mostrada quando se tenta acessar um WebService no browser, sem ter os metadados habilitados.

Um WebService, por padrão, não é feito para ser visualizado diretamente em um browser, como uma página HTML, ou uma foto.

Quando eu preciso testar um WebService (seja ASMX, ou qualquer outro tipo), utilizo uma nova instância do Visual Studio, com um novo projeto *dummy* em C#, conforme as imagens abaixo:

[image: Etapa 1]

[image: Etapa 2]

[image: Etapa 3]

Caso seja um serviço WCF, e você tenha o aplicativo `WCF Test Client` instalado, você também pode utilizá-lo para testar um serviço:

*No meu computador, ele fica aqui: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe`

[image: Etapa 4]

[image: Etapa 5]

[image: Etapa 6]

Comment: Pode adicionar normalmente. Mas esse esquema de como testar é só um exemplo. Caso você tenha instalado, você também pode testar o `WebService` através do **Microsoft WCF Test Client**.

Comment: Editei a resposta com esse outro exemplo...

Comment: Ele fornece esse(s) campo(s) automaticamente quando um método tem parâmetros.

Comment: Para determinar melhor, precisaria ver o código do `svc` e do `cs`.

Comment: Oi @pnet! Você deve editar a pergunta, e não a resposta ;)

Comment: Oi de novo, @pnet! Testei seu código, e fiz igualzinho. Funcionou perfeito, mas, três coisas que você deve se atentar: 1. Verifique todos os `namespace`, e veja se estão batendo. 2. Confira o `Markup` do arquivo `SuporteTecnico.svc` e veja se ele está ok. 3. Eu **removi** a entrada `<services><service name="SuporteTecnico">...</services>` do `Web.config`.

Comment: Quando vc diz funcionar, vc quer dizer que consegue passar parãmetro para o WS? Porque a tela que diz que o WS iniciou, para mim também é mostrada. O que não consigo é passar o parâmetro cnpj, nem pelo WCF ClientTest e nem pela aplicação que eu desenvolvi para isso. Continua o erro:The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.

Comment: Sim, inclusive passar parâmetros! Tentou excluir aquele trecho que te disse, do `Web.config`? Tente também remover o atributo `[DataContract(Namespace="")]` da sua classe `TPDV`, pois eu não acrescentei isso durante meus testes.

Comment: Sim, excluir sim. Excluir toda as tags desde <service><services>, tudo dentro dessas tags. Vou editar a minha pergunta e colocar meu novo web.config. Caso não resolva, vou refazer tudo outra vez.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, percebi que você nem chegou a chamar os métodos do seu webService seja o (hello... ou o dowork..). Não se esqueça do new em seu projeto.

Bom, verifiquei também que você não está referênciando o serviço da maneira correta. Existe uma certa diferença entre Service e WebService. A maneira correta para você realizar a referência seria essa:

Para adicionar uma Referência Web em seu projeto:
No Solution Explorer, clique com o botão direto no nome do projeto que você deseja adicionar o serviço. Depois, clique em Add Service Reference.
Aparecerá a janela Add Service Reference, clique no botão Advanced.
A janela Service Reference Settings irá aparecer, nela clique em:Add Web Reference. Depois basta colocar a url e etc...

Há uma certa diferença em ambas formas de adicionar uma referência no Visual Studio. Por isso exige esse certo conhecimento. 
Depois você faz como eu disse para dar o new na referência e utilizar os seus métodos.

Comment: Isso, exemplo: eu tenho um serviço que utilizo: br.com.nome.Nome api = new br.com.nome.Nome();

Comment: Mas `Advanced... > Add Web Reference...` não é apenas para adicionar referências, gerando compatibilidade com a tecnologia .Net Framework 2.0 Web Services?

Comment: Exato, mas isso também vem da diferença entre WCF e Web Services, podendo ser explicado  aqui: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139787/What-s-the-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-Services

Comment: Legal!!! :D Mas no caso dele, depois que respondi da primeira vez, não é nem a adição da referência em si, mas o teste utilizando a ferramenta `WCF Client`.

Comment: Tentando fazer funcionar via aplicação, agora pelo wcf client test me dá esse erro: Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.